Динамическое добавление атрибута в класс setattr()
Легенда:
Тренирую рыцарей. Класс:
class Knight:

    def __init__(self, color, horse):
        self.color = color
        self.horse = horse

Рыцари умеют только ничего не делать:
    def unknown_method(self, *args, redirect=False):
        if redirect:
            print(f'Some unknown method with name={args[0]} and args={args[1:]}')
        else:
            print(f'Usual unknown method and args={args}')

Создаю двух рыцарей:
knight = Knight('black', 'black and white')
knight2 = Knight('white', 'purple')

Если свежих рыцарей попросить сделать "то - не знаю что" (unknown_method (выше)), все по плану:
    knight.unknown_method(4, 6)
    knight.unknown_method(4, 8, 'стопиццот')

Для неизвестных изначально методов у них есть тренировка. Примерно:
    def __getattr__(self, method):
        def wrapper(*args):
            print(f'NAME OF NEW ATTR: {method}')
            self.unknown_method(method, *args, redirect=True)

        if method in self.__dict__:     # сюда мы не попадаем,
            print("YES", method)        # так как __getattr__ раньше найдет
            return method               # уже существующий метод
        else: 
                                   # А вот здесь нужно добавление метода(атрибута) не объекту 
                                   #класса (одному рыцарю)Б а всему классу:                          
            setattr(self, method, lambda *args: print(f'Already added method {method} with args={args}'))
            return wrapper

Нужно что-то вроде:
      setattr(self.__class__, method, lambda *args: print(f'Already added method {method} with args={args}')

Подскажите, как это сделать нормально, чтобы без дорогих костылей. Заранее спасибо

А может лучше не надо так делать?

Динамически добавлять атрибуты в класс? Или сейчас о другом речь...

Надо. А если это совсем плохая идея, то почему?

Так ваше "что-то вроде" же работает, что вы ещё хотите? Только если вызывать новый метод от экземпляра класса, будет ещё лишний аргумент - ссылка на экземпляр класса, собтвенно.

В класс хотите добавить новый метод что бы он появился для всех объектов класса?

Для любого из экземпляров класса вызывается существующий или еще не существующий метод (рыцарь1.иди(), рыцарь2.подпрыгни(), рыцарь3.присядь()) и этод метод автоматически добавляется в класс Рыцарь, но каждый из экземпляров класса его выполняет в зависимости от своего набора атрибутов и свойств. Метод в лоб setattr(self.class, method, lambda *args: func_1(*args}') рабочий, но он и тут уже вызвал скепсис. Если никто не накинет что-нибудь более удобное или очевидное или не запарафинят setattr, то его и оставлю. Sorry, только привыкаю к Python
